# Azure Dev Ops Deploying Angular Application To Static Web App

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, static

I want to deploy an Angular application to an Azure Static Web Application.The build part works fine but the release errors and says it can not find the build artifact : **Directory Location:** ***'dist' is invalid. Could not detect this directory. Please verify your deployment configuration file reflects your repository structure.***

This is the YAML used for the application publish, screenshot below that.

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: dist'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: dist
    ArtifactName: dist
```

[Static Web App templete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KACxw.png)

So it seems that we are not using the correct publish location but not sure what to use.

**The following is the YAML from the pipeline :**

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli -g'

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build -- --configuration=production'

steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: dist'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: dist/CarehomeBooking
    ArtifactName: dist
```

The directory structure of the built Angular app is :

[AngularBuiltCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf3sU.png)

Comment: Could you please share your Pipeline code and directory structure of your artifact?

Comment: Added details above to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

The `PathToPublish` needs to have the output folder of the `ng build` action. Please make sure to build a release version of your project. You might need to run either `ng build --prod`, `ng build --configuration production` or simply `ng build` to make sure you build a release version depending on what version of Angular (CLI) you are on.

The default output path for current Angular projects is: **`dist/<projectName>`**

Find your output path by opening up the `angular.json` file and looking at the `outputPath` under `architect` -> `build` -> `options`.

Also: make sure you run the command from the root of the project or specify the full path.

Comment: Hi, I tried making some of your suggested changes but I now get the error : 2021-08-11T17:07:51.4931321Z [37mDetecting platforms...[0m
2021-08-11T17:09:00.4466669Z [31mError: Oops... An unexpected error has occurred.[0m

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the built Angular artefact to the original question.